# compiler not running tableview datasource methods

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

I met a question that i ensured setted datasource and delegate ，implemention  two datasource methods ，but compiler not runnin this two methods，have someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `self` to tableView's dataSource, you have to make sure your tableView is not nil, then everything will be ok.

Comment: under your guides ,I resolved my problem . thinks for your help!